# JQuery translate function not working in firefox / chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, translate

I have a HTML page which is divided into two frames. Separate web sites are being opened by users in those frames as I provided an open web site option.

These web sites can be in any language. So. i need to translate the languages of these websites to English.

I am using JQuery translate function for this which is not working. As I am new to JQuery, I may be using incorrect syntax / way.

I have tried this code in Firefox, which is not working.
I have tried in Chrome, but I am not able to know that it is working or not because of the default language translate option of the Google Chrome.
I have also searched StackOverFlow Questions, but I didn't find anything.

```
$(function(){ //on document ready
  $('body').translate('en');
})
```

Here is a link to the plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/TranslateMethod

Comment: I assume you've loaded the plugin in your document `head`?

Comment: I have tried both in head and body tags

Comment: Do you see any error in firebug console?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/TranslateMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the jQuery library and the script should be called from one of the frames, not the container page, otherwise it won't work.

The jQuery function `jQuery()` (or `$()`) looks by default in the current document. In order to apply that function to a frame you should specify the context as a second argument of the function. In this case it would be like:

```
$(function() {
    $('body', window.parent.frames[0].document).translate('en');
});
```

You can obviously change the index of the array `frames` (`frames[0]`, `frames[1]`, ecc..) to match the frame that you want to translate.

**edit**: you can also set a name to the frame (putting the attribute `name` in the tag `<frame>` and then call it using `window.frame_name.document`.